# Serially queueing conditional HTTP requests with AFNetworking and NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, afnetworking, nsoperation

I am refactoring some existing code.  It has about 20 HTTP requests which are executed serially, assuming the previous one returns HTTP status 200 (OK).  If the status is not 200, the process stops.  The current code is a mess of delegate callbacks, instance variables, a giant `switch` statement, and separate methods for each call.

I'd like to use AFNetworking instead.  I figure that I will need to make a series of `AFJSONRequestOperation` objects and put them into an NSOperationQueue with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to `1` so it runs serially.

The default behavior of an NSOperationQueue is to continue through the operations whether or not the previous operation was successful.  However I would like the queue to cancel all operations if one of the operations calls its failure block (for example, if the HTTP request returns 404 (file not found)).

Since the behavior of [AFJSONRequestOperation](http://engineering.gowalla.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFJSONRequestOperation.html) is not very configurable, do I need to subclass it to achieve what I want?  Is there another built-in feature of AFNetworking that will allow me to do this simply?

Comment: you could call cancel on the queue if there is a failure in one of your requests... see `cancelAllOperations` here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Wouldn't that require putting a slightly different variation of the same conditional in every failure block?  I'm trying to avoid repeating myself if possible...

Comment: I'm not sure what other options there are. I haven't used `AFJSONRequestOperation`. I have done this type of serial requests where whenever there is a failure the queue gets cancelled. You could wrap the call to `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` so that your request, success, and failure are all handled consistently.

Comment: Can't you just recursively call the method that starts the downloads from the didReceiveResponse method based on the response you get?

Comment: Yeah, I could put the requests in a collection and iterate through them using a recursive function.  It seemed like it might be a common use case, so I wanted to know if there was an existing AFNetworking class or other library I should look at.

Comment: You could have a subclass that does the cancelling...

Comment: I believe there lies a way in http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html
One way I can think of: You could override HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure: (http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:) of the AFHTTPClient and do the cancellation of the operations there.
This way, you would have abstracted not only the network code, but operation queue handling code too from you actual code.

Comment: @AaronBrager You ask "Wouldn't that require putting a slightly different variation of the same conditional in every failure block?" No, the `failure` block would be identical. You're just calling `cancelAllOperations` for the queue.